How can quantisation slow down a model?
I'm working with the SentenceTransformers library with one of their embedding models. The performance is good, but I'd like to trade some accuracy for higher performance. I've tried quantising the model I'm working with, but rather than improving performance, it made it worse.
Here's how I've quantised the model:
import torch
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer

torch.backends.quantized.engine = 'qnnpack'

model = SentenceTransformer("all-MiniLM-L6-v2", device="cpu")

quantized_model_8bit = torch.quantization.quantize_dynamic(
    model,  # the original model
    {torch.nn.Linear},  # layers to quantize
    dtype=torch.qint8  # quantization data type
)

Why does this happen?
